# Strange behaviour of Class instance - when updating internal variables

Tags: python, class, object

Let's say I define the following class in Python.

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = self.x ** 2
    def check(self):
        self.x = self.x + 1
        print self.x
        print self.y
```

Here I have two internal variables x and y. In the initialization I have set $$ y = x^2 $$. Now each time I call the method `check()` it increments the value of x by 1 : `self.x = self.x + 1`. However when I print the values x correctly increments by 1 but y remains 0 always. (Should'nt it be x^2??) What's going wrong?

Comment: Nothing is going wrong. You never change `self.y` after you have initialized the instance, so it retains the same value it always had.

Comment: I highly recommend Ned Batchelder's “[Facts and Myths about Python Names and Values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html)” (26 minute [video from PyCon US 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns)) for a crash course in how Python variables and assignment statements are not at all like most other languages'.  (Specifically, names always refer to values, _never_ to expressions or other names.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `self.y` is only assigned when you **first** create an instance of your class. It is not updated every time you call a function. The `def __init__(self):` function is only executed when you do
`myVar = new test()`, therefore the value of y is only assigned and updated once.

Your code would need to be:

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = self.x ** 2
    def check(self):
        self.x = self.x + 1
        self.y = self.x ** 2
        print self.x
        print self.y
```

Answer (score 2):

Python is not like a spreadsheet where updating one cell (variable) can automatically affect the values of others.

Following initialisation, the code never changes the value of `self.y`. You need to add some code to do that, e.g.

```
    def check(self):
        self.x = self.x + 1
        self.y = self.x ** 2
        print self.x
    print self.y
```

---

There is a way to implement that behaviour though: use [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = 0
        self.y = 0

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value
        self.y = value ** 2

    def check(self):
        self.x = self.x + 1
        print self.x, self.y

>>> t = Test()
>>> for i in range(5):
...     t.check()
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25

>>> t.x = 200
>>> t.y
40000
```

If you wanted you can also implement `y` as a property and have it set `x` to its square root when it's updated. This would enforce the relationship that `x` is the square root of `y`` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `y` is only set when it is instantiated and does not get updated in your code.

You should have separate methods to update and/or increment `x` and adjust `y` as necessary, along with your method to check the values.

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
    def update_x(self, x):
        self.x = x
        self.y = x ** 2
    def increment_x(self):
        self.x += 1
        self.y = self.x ** 2
    def check(self):
        print self.x
        print self.y
```